# Authlogic password isn't encrypted in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication

I am starting to use Authologic for the authentication of RoR application.

I noticed that even though I am using:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
end
```

The password isn't encrypted in my database (postgres).

Comment: If you are creating a new app there is no reason to use `Sha512`  - it's there for compatibility with apps that have old passwords. Use the default SCrypt instead. https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic

Comment: Note: I have no idea... but if I were to guess, I'd say it might not actually do the encryption on your local dev database... (might be worth reading the docs to see if that's the case)

Comment: @max Yes, it's a new application. I will give a try to SCrypt. I am looking to hash passwords in database and expect authlogic to compare hashes